# google play store show different information in mobile and PC

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have developed an app on google play,link provided as below
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tw.blogspot.httpcodecrazer.taiwanrain

I have used in app-billing in beta testing, however, I remove it in my formal release, and I delete

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING">
```

It works when I look at google play in my phone, In app billing purchasing message disappear,however,in PC, the same URL still show in app purchasing, I google but found nothing useful, how can I solve it? Thank you!

Comment: Updating info takes a while. Wait for a few hours until you check again. It is slow, may be some differences in platforms as well

Comment: @LunarWatcher It's almost 24hour after I update it

Comment: Google Play is slow. How slow varies, but desktop updates I think take longer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mail to the google official, and the solution to this problem is that you have to also delete the permission code in beta version, it means that you have to upload another apk without permssion code to beta version, I tried the method, and it really works, hope this post help people who also have the same problem